# Struts parameters not accessible in <s:if> tag

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl, http-request-parameters, struts-tags

I have a .jsp page that does the following check to see if it should display an error message:

```
<s:if test="#parameters.error == 1">
    <ul><li>
        <s:text name="login.error"/>
    </li></ul>
</s:if>
```

The error parameter comes from the request parameter (i.e. /myPage.action?error=1).

I've debugged the jsp page into the org.apache.struts2.views.jspComponentTagSupport.doStartTag() method and from there I can access the ValueStack and see that the HttpParameters object does contain an "error" parameter, which I can access via:

```
stack.getContext().get("parameters")).get("error")).getValue();
```

This will return a String with the value of `1` as expected.
However, debugging down through the code further it seems that it's not properly evaluating the test attribute of the `<s:if>` tag.
The `ognl.ASTEq.getValueBody(OgnlContext, Object)` method attempts to get the value of the 'children' of the parsed test query.  
It ends up in the `ognl.OgnlRuntime.getFieldValue(OgnlContext, Object, String, boolean)` method which returns a `NotFound` result, even though the HttpParameters contains the value it's looking for (`"error"`).

It seems like this is a bug in struts/ognl for how it's parsing the parameters on the value stack, but I'm not sure.

**I'm using Struts 2.5.5. Recently upgraded from Struts 2.3.x and this code worked fine with that version** so either it's a bug or something changed in how these properties are accessed that I'm not aware of.

Comment: If the error is saved in the request in the back end, then on the jsp you can access it with "#request.error" something like that.

Comment: This may also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40327981/struts-upgrade-to-2-5-5-from-2-5-3

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi And should be reopened.

Comment: ... reopened :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios , AleksandrM , thanks for reopening!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a short research, it could be due to [Issue WW-4572](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4572), AKA the refactoring of the Parameter management, from a `Map` of `Objects` to an `HttpParameter` class containing `Parameter` objects, shipped with version  **2.5.5**.

Looking at the [`Parameter` class](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/Parameter.java), it seems it should be enough to call the `value` attribute on it, like:

```
<s:if test="%{#parameters.error.value == 1}">
```

I hope is that, but meanwhile: try using more of the framework mechanisms and less the request parameters (eg. use an error variable with getter and setter on a base action, or even better, use `actionErrors` and `fieldErrors` to carry the messages, and check for their presence to detect when an error occurred).

Comment: Using #parameters.value.error didn't work, but I added an error variable on the action and can access it using <s:if test="%{error ==1}">, which is probably better anyway as you mentioned.  I still think there is a bug in how struts is parsing the parameters that likely was introduced by [WW-4572](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4572).

Comment: There was a typo in the answer, can you please try with `error.value` instead of `value.error` ?

Comment: No, that doesn't work either.  It seems to be parsing it incorrectly from what I'm seeing in my debugger.  It can access the HttpParameters on the value stack, but seems like it parses parameters and error as separate field names and tries to find them independently on the stack, so instead of getting the HttpParameters via the parameters field and then looking for error in the HttpParameters, it looks for the error field on the value stack itself (at least that's my best guess as to what it's doing right now).

Comment: Here we go ;) +1 for identifying the cause.

Comment: Please report an issue in JIRA, it's related to change mentioned by @AndreaLigios

Answer (score 3):

**Only** in **Struts 2.5.5**.

If you want to check value of the `error` parameter then:

```
<s:if test="#parameters.get('error').value == 1">
    <ul><li>
        <s:text name="login.error"/>
    </li></ul>
</s:if>
```

If you want to check whether parameter exists:

```
<s:if test="#parameters.contains('error')">
</s:if>
```

Andrea is right about the cause and about using request parameters.

Comment: This worked. It should be listed on the migration page at https://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-23-to-25-migration.html .

Comment: @rveach No. It is only for 2.5.5.